# JavaFX control in TabPane doesn't receive input events

Tags: java, scala, javafx-2, javafx

I have a problem with JavaFX when trying to add a custom control onto a BorderPane in my app. As long as I just set my control (Editor) as the content (using setCenter) it works just fine and receives input events (keyboard and mouse). However, when I try to wrap it into a TabPane and Tab control the control doesn't receive any events any more and can't seem to be focussed. I know the control is still there in the Scene, because you can still see it. You just can't interact with it.

The following code is what I'm working with right now:

```
class EditorScene extends BorderPane {

  def setup() {
    // Default editor
    val tab = new javafx.scene.control.Tab("New File")
    val editor = new Editor(this)
    tab.setContent(editor)

    val tabs = new TabPane()
    tabs.getTabs().add(tab)

    setCenter(tabs)
    //setCenter(editor)
  }

  setup()
}
```

In the last lines of setup() when I use the second line (setCenter(editor)) it works as expected, receives events etc. When I use the line above (setCenter(tabs)) it doesn't receive any events apparently; at least the event handlers are not called.

I'm probably overlooking something very obvious, but I can't seem to find the mistake. Any ideas? I'd be grateful for any hints.

Comment: It seems the TabPane is stealing the focus of the child elements. If I add an event handler to the TabPane via onSetKeyPressed and let it just call the editor's requestFocus() method, it works.

Comment: Could you rewrite piece of code on java, and write listeners there (which catch, or don't catch events), because, trying to reproduce the app from this snippet, I cannot catch the idea (I even cannot understand, which content should catch events, if there is no content, which has size.

Comment: I think, that, when you set editor as a content of tab, as it has no content and size, it is collapsed, and don't receive mouse events, but, when you put editor into editor, internal editor will be of the same size, as outer editor, so it will receive mouse events. About focus - if you set a text field as a content of tab, textfield will have focus. The trouble is that layouts are not supposed to have a focus in usual case, and you run into that fact, when you add a focusable control on the scene.

Comment: I tried to play with a similar application, and seems, didn't find anything unusual (I mean, all behavior was predictable, about events propogation). I need you code to be more clear (what is Editor class, for instance) to explain you the troubles. Previously, I can say, that if you want to understand, what is happening, you should look at focusTraversable() property, and its default values for layouts (false) and controls (usually - true). Focusable controls can receive events, and if don't consume,  it will be propogated up.

Comment: Also, try to track value of Scene.focusOwnerProperty()

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Maybe the problem is that my editor is not actually an "official" input control. It's my own implementation of a text input control and actually only consists of a BorderPane and Text controls. I uploaded a representative test case to GitHub: https://github.com/Bunkerbewohner/javafx-testcase